# Is there an equivalent of Oracle dba_profiles in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, edb

I am trying to run select query on one of the objects(dba_profiles) in postgres and getting an error as 'SQL: Database error ERROR:  permission denied for view dba_profiles' and upon trying to grant permission for the same to my user, it is throwing an error as follows :
Command is - sv=> GRANT SELECT ON TABLE dba_profiles TO "MY_USER";
ERROR:  permission denied for table dba_profiles

So, is there any other command to grant permission to this table by not getting into superuser mode and staying in normal mode. Or is there any equivalent of it which can directly be used in postgres? Help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Rohit

Comment: There is no view or table dba_profiles, so there is no way to grant permission on it. What information do you want to get from that profiles table? What problem are you trying to solve with that information?

Comment: I am into migration from Oracle to EDB Postgres, dba_profiles is being used in one of the queries in Oracle for which I need to find its equivalent to support the same in EDB Postgres. Now that you say there is no such view or table, can you please tell what can be used in place of it to support that part in EDB Postgres? Thanks

Comment: What information do you want to get from that profiles table? What problem are you trying to solve with that information?

Comment: Yes Si, i am just running a query 'SELECT * FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE PROFILE = Profile_Name' and assigning it to a variable and further using that variable to check if a profile exists. And this is happening for oracle at the moment, but as i told you, i am doing the migration from Oracle to EDB Postgres, so i need the EDB Postrgres equivalent to frame the similar query with an object like dba_profiles compatible with EDB Postgres. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are using EDB Advanced Server then this is a tech support question for EDB. @a_horse_with_no_name,  EDB Advanced Server does have `dba_profiles` as part of its Oracle compatibility layer.